# Elastic search query operation is slow using Spark with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I am a newbie to Spark, as a part of learning I was trying to query elasticsearch index. I could successfully read the data from index using spark sql but the performance is too slow. To read 100K records it is taking more than 40mins. While the same is achieved in 10mins using Map-reduce.

Below is the spark configuration that I am using.

```
spark-submit --class com.esexample.ReadES --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 10g --executor-memory 10g --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 5 --queue default readES-1-1.0-uber.jar "ES Example " "/user/hadoop/output" "yarn"
```

ES properties used :

```
"es.scroll.size" -> "10000",
"es.batch.size.entries" -> "10000",
"es.batch.size.bytes" -> "100mb",
"pushdown", "true"
```

For processing I am using Core - 4*m4.4xl and Master - 1*m4.xl nodes

Any insights on this will be appreciated.

Comment: The main approach to give more fast solution is use more fast memory and transfer less amount of data via slow channels. I think, you should setting params according your RAM

Comment: And it takes time not to read, but to create inverse index, as i think. Test it on more smaller amount of data, e.g., on 10k records.